# What does lit mean in unreal engine 4?

Tags: unreal-engine4

The Shading Model in UE4 has options like default lit and unlit.
What does lit stand for?
I guess lit stands for "light", But why? 
lit is not short enough.

Comment: Also *"unlight"* isn't a word! It doesn't stand for light, it's the past participle of that verb. *"Are you going to light that? It was lit, but it went out."*

Comment: WOW~~~~Jonrsharpe, great answer! I am not a native english speaker, thank you.

Comment: No problem; note that there is another SE network site for questions like this: http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: a good place! I bookmarked the link. thanks.